# No incoming connection for PhpStorm with xdebug (nginx / php-fpm)

Tags: nginx, xdebug, php

I figured I'd try using nginx instead of Apache and see how that works, and I'm up and running, but I cannot for the sake of my life figure out how to make PhpStorm capture the incoming xdebug connection. It worked perfectly when I was running Apache.

Usually, you'd get an "incoming connection"-window in PhpStorm - this window now shines with its absence - and yes; I've read every single PhpStorm / Xdebug question on StackOverflow and neither has solved my issue.

Configuration:
OS: OSX Mavericks
PhpStorm version: 7.1
Xdebug version: 2.2.5

Note that I'm running nginx and PHP through `php-fpm` which is working as expected. I've pointed out the same PHP-file as php-fpm is running to PhpStorm which successfully finds Xdebug as the debugger.

Since `php-fpm` is running port 9000 just as Xdebug, I've changed this to 9900 and 9001 (tried both) and made sure to check my `phpinfo()` to see that the server has updated the php.ini config with it and I've checked that I've updated the Xdebug port in PhpStorm. I've also enabled "Start listening for debug connections" in PhpStorm.

Xdebug config from php.ini:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension = /usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.14/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/xdebug.so
xdebug.auto_trace=0
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/tmp"
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_port=9001
```

As mentioned - xdebug is loaded when I load `phpinfo()` in the browser and I've set the correct port in PhpStorm.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there was one thing I missed when I changed the settings - stopping to listen for breakpoints and then trying again. This seems to have fixed the issue...

Comment: Could you add additional code to your answer, to show what works (and is different) to the original problematic code?

Comment: There's nothing different at all in the config. The only thing I was missing, apparently, was to stop listening for connections, reload, then start listening for connections again. Don't forget to set the cookie for Xdebug. Also, the file I was debugging was just a "Hello World!"-one liner for setting up my new environment with nginx.

Comment: It's a button on the top right that looks like a phone, small button. When hovering it, the tooltip says "Start Listening for PHP debug Connections". It's part of the toolbar "Navigation Bar", so if you can't find the button, choose "View" in the menu and make sure that "Navigation Bar" is checked.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot stress enough the importance of one of the remarks - "**Don't forget to set the cookie for xdebug**".
I had everything right and my debugger still wouldn't attach due to this.
One recommendation I can make is to install [**xdebug helper**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc) chrome extension. Once you have it, start the debug from PhpStorm, navigate to the page you want to debug and turn on the debug setting in the extension by clicking the "bug" icon within address bar.

Comment: Also double check that you have the xdebug.remote_enable = 1 set in your php.ini. They kind of slip this into the xdebug setup step of the tutorial on the PHPStorm site along with bunch of other substeps, whereas all the following steps are super granular, so it's easy to miss if you just glance at that step and say "Yup, I have xdebug installed."

Answer (score 0):

Here is my case.

- make sure xdebug is installed. `<?php echo (extension_loaded('xdebug') ? '' : 'non '), 'exists';`
- make sure the port is not used, an example is 

  `nginx server:9000  <->  php-fpm:9000
  ide_xdebug:9080 <-> php.ini_xdebug:9080`

Answer (score 0):

When having configured `xdebug.remote_host=` it is sometimes necessary to add also the option `xdebug.remote_connect_back=0` .

When PhpStorm complains 'Can't listen to port, port 9000 is busy` it is usually as some other application uses the same port for example via docker expose or ports settings or itself not being in docker.